# ConcurrentBag FirstOrDefault NullCheck throws

Tags: c#, .net, nullreferenceexception

I've got a Problem at my null check .

```
if (element == null)
```

throws

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Why can a simple null check fail at this Point? When i make a breakpoint at this Position, element has the value "null", but throws the exception anyway.

PS: At this Point, are no additional Threads active.

```
internal static ConcurrentBag<Node_Library> AddFileDetail(
                   this ConcurrentBag<Node_Library> list, 
                       FileDetails file , Node<Node_Application> app)
        {
            var element = list.FirstOrDefault(x => file.Equals(x));
            if (element == null)
            {
                list.Add(new Node_Library(file, app));
            }
            else
            {
                if (!element.ApplicationNodes.Contains(app))
                {
                    element.AddNode(app);
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
```

EDIT: file is not null, the list is empty but not null

EDIT2: Operator and FileDetail details

```
public class FileDetails
{
 internal string FileName {  get; private set; }
    internal string Name {  get; private set;}
    internal string Endung { get; private set; }
    internal string Version { get; private set; }
    internal string Produkt { get; private set; }
    internal string ProduktVersion { get; private set; }
    internal FileTyp Filetyp { get; private set; }
    internal string Pfad { get; private set; }

    public static bool operator==(FileDetails file1, Node_Library library)
    {
        return
            file1.Version == library.Version &&
            file1.Produkt == library.Produkt &&
            file1.ProduktVersion == library.ProduktVersion &&
            file1.FileName == library.FileName;
    }
    public static bool operator !=(FileDetails file1, Node_Library library)
    {
        return
            !(file1.Version == library.Version &&
            file1.Produkt == library.Produkt &&
            file1.ProduktVersion == library.ProduktVersion &&
            file1.FileName == library.FileName);
    }


    public static bool operator ==(FileDetails file1, FileDetails  file2)
    {
        if (
            file1.FileName == file2.FileName &&
            file1.Produkt == file2.Produkt &&
            file1.ProduktVersion == file2.ProduktVersion &&
            file1.Version == file2.Version)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    public static bool operator !=(FileDetails file1, FileDetails file2)
    {
        if (
             file1.Name == file2.Name &&
             file1.Produkt == file2.Produkt &&
             file1.ProduktVersion == file2.ProduktVersion &&
             file1.Version == file2.Version)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    internal bool Equals(Node_Library file2)
    {

        if (file2 == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return (
          Name == file2.Name &&
          Produkt == file2.Produkt &&
          ProduktVersion == file2.ProduktVersion &&
          Version == file2.Version);
    }

//More Stuff
}
```

EDIT3: 
I used a breakpoint in my equal overload, but it never triggered... So the problem is maybe the FirstOrDefault?

finally: 
Operatoroverload was faulty. Fixed it. Ty a lot.

Comment: @JeffRSon  `FileDetails file`, see the method parameters

Comment: ...which doesn't seem to be a standard .net class...?

Comment: Doing a `FirstOrDefault()` and later doing a `list.Add(...)` doesn't seem to be a correct use of the `ConcurrentBag`

Comment: Why are you returning the `list`?

Comment: I doubt that the problem lies in `if (element == null) `. Did you create `operators` for `FileDetails`?   _operator ==_

Comment: Please post you `FileDetails.Equals` implementation.

Comment: well, on second view - it's hard to understand like your snippet is written: how could a `FileDetails` instance be equal to a `Node_Library` (which is in your `ConcurrentBag`)

Comment: Added the Operator and Equal functions

Comment: Unless you provide a minimal, complete, verifyable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's probably not possible to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your operators:

```
public static bool operator==(FileDetails file1, Node_Library library)
{
    return
        file1.Version == library.Version &&
        file1.Produkt == library.Produkt &&
        file1.ProduktVersion == library.ProduktVersion &&
        file1.FileName == library.FileName;
}
```

When you compare an instance to `null` it's trying to access the properties `Version`, `Produkt`, `ProduktVersion` and `FileName` from a `null` instance, hence the `NullReferenceException`.

So, answering to your initial question `"Why can a simple null check fail at this Point?"`, it's because there's nothing simple about that null check once you override the operators.  =D

To solve it, you can add a null check on `file2`:

```
public static bool operator ==(FileDetails file1, FileDetails  file2)
{
    if (file2 != null &&
        file1.FileName == file2.FileName &&
        file1.Produkt == file2.Produkt &&
        file1.ProduktVersion == file2.ProduktVersion &&
        file1.Version == file2.Version)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Try the second `operator==`, the one with `(FileDetails file1, FileDetails  file2)`, I think it's the default, since the two parameters are equal. I edited the answer.

Comment: Can't add it to this function VS says _Operator '!=' is ambiguous on operands of type 'FileDetails' and '<null>'_

Comment: Long shot, but try casting to `object`, like `(object)file2 != null` or `file2 as object != null`.

Comment: Actually, if `list` is empty the operators shouldn't matter, should they?

Comment: The error is in the `if (element == null)` line, after searching the list.

Comment: Ah, yes, well, the naming of types and variables here is quite confusing. Nevertheless, since elements should be of type Node_Library, operators of FileDetails don't matter. The callstack would be useful as well. It's a pity this question requires so much comments and requests for clarification.

Comment: Ty a lot. It was the opperator.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be the previous line:

```
var element = list.FirstOrDefault(x => file.Equals(x));
```

The `file` parameter is probably `null`.

EDIT: If `file` is not null, then the `FileDetails.Equals` method can be the culprit.

Comment: Could be, but as this is an extension method, I'm assuming it's being called from an initialized instance. What raises me a doubt: can I call an extension method from a `null` variable? Going to check right now! =)

Comment: The List is empty, but not null. The parameter file is not null as well.